# Accessing PHP variable in jQuery with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have the following defined in my controller:

```
$data['is_amazon'] = $product->is_amazon;
$data['is_ebay']   = $product->is_ebay;
```

Directly below this in the controller I'm calling a .js file (jQuery).

```
$this->template->add_js('js/is_ebay_amazon_prouct_edit.js');
```

I'd like to access these php variables in my jQuery script, I've tried this approach:

```
var amazon = '<?php echo $is_amazon; ?>';
var ebay = '<?php echo $is_ebay; ?>';


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    alert(amazon);
    //alert(ebay);

});
```

Although this just displays my physical text in the alert, I.E:

```
<?php echo $is_ebay; ?>
```

What is the best approach here in terms of making these variables accessible in my jQuery?

Comment: You can't add the php code into js files. PHP code only run in .php files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

do one thing.. you need to create two input hiddent field in view.
like this

```
<input type='hidden' id="amazon" value="<?php echo $is_amazon; ?>" />
<input type='hidden' id="ebay" value="<?php echo $is_ebay; ?>" />
```

and call that value in you jquery lik this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //alert($('#amazon').val()+" "+$('#ebay').val());   

     console.log("amazon"+$('#amazon').val());
     console.log("ebay"+$('#ebay').val());    
});
```

now it will work for u.. try it.

Comment: Still no joy unfortunately, the  alert still displays the php code: <?=$is_amazon; ?>

Comment: wait I will update my answer

Comment: its work or not for you now.

Comment: Creating extra DOM elements just to hold on to php variables means unnecessary DOM bloat.  I do not recommend this technique.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to directly assign php variables to javascript. To do this you need to assign assign it to html elements like,

```
<input type="hidden" id ="amazon" value="<?php echo $is_amazon; ?>">
```

We can get the value in jquery from this html element by using this code,

```
var amazon = $('#amazon').val();
```

For security reasons the php variables cant assign to javascript variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="hidden" id="fromAmazon" value="<?php echo $is_amazon ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" id="fromEbay" value="<?php echo $is_ebay ?>"/>
```

In jquery
After loading jquery.js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var amazon = $("#fromAmazon").val();
    var ebay = $("#fromEbay").val();

    console.log("amazon",amazon);
    console.log("ebay",ebay);

});
```